# How to prove the two angles are equal?

Tags: geometry, physics

[image]
It is from Young Double slit experiment. But How to prove the the two $\theta$ are equal, I meant, how  $\angle EAD= \angle PEC$? I see from the both triagle have $90^0$ but what about others.

If we think θ→0 we get valid results. we can see the image from any article whoch is YOUNG's double slit experiment. citycollegiate.com/interference2.htm

Comment: Hmmmm ... Presumably, $\overline{AB} \parallel \overline{PC}$. Therefore, $\angle ABP \cong \angle CPB$ as *alternate interior angles* for those parallel lines. Now, in $\triangle ABD$, we have $\theta = 90^\circ - \angle ABP$. However, in $\triangle EPC$, we have $\theta = 90^\circ - \angle CPE$. But $\angle CPE$ is clearly larger than $\angle CPB$, and therefore also larger than $\angle ABP$. The two $\theta$s don't match. Are you sure that you've annotated the diagram correctly?

Comment: but if you think $\theta \rightarrow 0$ we get valid results. you can see the image from any article whoch is YOUNG's double slit experiment. http://www.citycollegiate.com/interference2.htm

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, we let $L$ be large and hence, have $\theta$ is a small value. We then do computations on $\sin\theta$, $\cos\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ based on small $\theta$.

Comment: If you want the two angles equal, then either (1) put $D$ on $EP$ with a right angle, rather than on $BP$ or (2) put $C$ as the perpendicular point from $B$ measuring $\angle PBC$ rather than measuring  $\angle PEC$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe both the angles can be equal only when L is infinity. Here is why---

If ∠PEC =  θ then ∠AEP = 90 - θ

So in small triangle AEO  where O is the point of intersection of EP and AD :--

∠AOE = 180 - (θ + 90 - θ) = 90

Now because ∠AOE = ∠ADB = 90 so it follows that EP and BP are parallel. It is only possible when L is infinity.

Does the answer make sense to you...??

Comment: then ,$\angle ADB$ will be invalid. When we do mathematical problems for this theory we use the L finite.

Comment: You do not need $O$. Compare $\angle AEP =  90^\circ - \angle PEC$ and $\angle ABP =  90^\circ - \angle EAD$  ; if they are the same then $EP$ and $BP$ must be parallel (which would be true if they were coincident and $d=0$)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the angles are 'equal' is based on the assumption given in the original post.

It says "Since the value of 'd' is very very small as compared to L, therefore, θ will also be very small. In this condition we can assume that : sin θ = tan θ".